# Xaml Grid Styling

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

New to WPF, I'm having some trouble creating a styles in my code, I was able to make some buttons styles by drawing rectangles and making them into buttons, this opened a template editor so I was able to do it.

Now I'm wanting to create a template for a repeating stackpanel/grid layout, and I wrote it by hand this time, but I am getting an error that says the "template is not a valid member"

This is the kind of thing I was trying to create, but the Property="Template" bit is underlined in red. Can somebody explain to me the reason behind this? How do I create or initialize the template?

```
<Style x:Key="LaneStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="760"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
                    <!-- Things here -->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If someone could direct me to a tutorial on styles/templates that would be nice as well, haven't been able to find one that explained it in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Grid` is not a control, therefore you cannot apply a `ControlTemplate` to it. If you're looking for a "repeater" kind of thing, you should be using an `ItemsControl`.

Comment: How could I have say, labels within the itemscontrol that I could change, would I need to nest them in the itemscontrol or would it be possible to include them within the template that is repeated? I don't see that happening but it would be nice

Comment: @harrier most of the time you don't need to override an `ItemsControl` `Template`. You only need to define it's `ItemTemplate`. Look at [this tutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/ListBoxDataTemplate.html) for more information.

Comment: Well, I need some bound data in there that is fine, but basically I have 6 repeats of the itemscontrol and I want each one to have a different numbered label in, as well as labels for the bound data which can remain within the template. Surely I would have to override that?

Comment: @Herrier you may also use nested `ItemsControls` (meaning putting an `ItemsControl` inside the `ItemTemplate` of the parent `ItemsControl`. I suggest you post some screenshot of what you need so I can tell you how to do it in WPF.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I think I'll be able to make it work from here, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to create templates/styles is by using Microsoft Blend 3.0/4.0
Over there one can easily find out what's the progress after doing each change.

In your case, a grid cannot be styled as it is a container not a control. If you wish to customize some control need to modify the control template of the control.